# Can I send a message from a receiver back to the sender?

Tags: javascript, chromecast

I have started working on a Chromecast app based on the Chrome API, using a custom Receiver.

I have got the sender talking to the receiver, sending message payloads successfully.

But, is there a way for the receiver to send message payloads back to the specific sender, e.g. to give feedback on operations?

I can't seem to find anything about this in the Chromecast Documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a receiver application can both send a message to a targeted sender (`send(senderId, message)`) or send a broadcast message to all connected senders (`broadcast(message)`). Look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager#onSenderDisconnected) for more details.

Comment: Erm, I am NOT using that link you put, it asks for me to log in! I'll try and find it in the real Google Docs

Comment: @MrPablo http://stackoverflow.com/users/601869/mr-pablo the externally available link to the Class cast.receiver.CastMessageBus is https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/receiver/cast.receiver.CastMessageBus

Comment: Fixed the link to point at a public facing site, sorry for that.